# How can I link a profile I created using Facebook with my e-mail?

Tags: support, login, email

I used the sign up with Facebook option when I first got this account, which caused me to have this user name. I want to add an e-mail address so I can be notified to activity on my questions. I also sent an e-mail to the Stack Exchange team about this but they did not respond. I tried an article on how I could merge two profiles, but that didn't work.

Comment: Do you have anything in the email address box when you go to this page: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/email/settings/381074 ?